# Run code only once

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I cant figure out how to run a part of code in `ViewDidLoad()` method **only once**. I don't want that part of the code to be executed until the app is started again. Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=run+code+once+in+application&oq=run+code+once+in+application&aqs=chrome..69i57.8238j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=run+code+once+in+ios+application

Comment: dispatch_once is certainly a viable solution. It is also quite common to have a bool property that is set the first time the code is run, which is checked for subsequent calls to viewDidLoad. I would be interested, though, in knowing what part of a viewDidLoad code should be run only once? Maybe that part belongs somewhere else than in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Handsomeguy Setting UISlider's position programmatically(code to be run once).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_once` in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^
{
    // Code to run once
});
```

This will make the code run only once until you exit and close your app.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set up a BOOL flag to check whether the code has executed.

set up the bool above the implementation in the .m file:

```
static BOOL codeExecuted = NO;
```

in the -viewDidLoad() method:

```
if (!codeExecuted)
{

    //run code
    codeExecuted = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    <#code to be executed once#>
});
```

You can use `dispatch_once` to specify a certain code block be executed only once ever for that run of an application

Answer (score 1):

Then You should put your code in Application delegate

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     // Your code will run only once per  launch

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will serve your need:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        <#code to be executed once#>
    });
```

Comment: This limits it to once per run of the application. This will not work if you need it called once in multiple instances of the same view controller class (i.e. once per instance).

Answer (score 0):

Add that code in your app's appdelegate method didfinishlaunchingwithoptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     // Your code will run only when app is launched

  }
```